# Apache NiFi - Data Provenance

Tags: apache-nifi

I've a question regarding Data Provenance option provided by Apache NiFi.

The search option provided in Data Provenance page has options to search based on EventType, FlowFileId etc. Usually with in a flow file multiple 
records can be there, and in most of the case we would be interested in searching based on a particular value (for example, an event id which comes as part of data).

Does data provenance supports this ?

Or I understood it wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, by using [**Data provenance search**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#searching-for-events) we are able to search only on the **`flowfile attribute`** level, not on the **`flowfile content(data)`**.

- We cannot change the parameters that are included in the Data provenance search dialog window.

***Other ways to filter on flowfile content:***

- To query on flowfile data level then we need to use ***`QueryRecord`*** processor

  (or)
- We need to extract the flowfile data and keep as attribute to the flowfile then by using ***`RouteOnAttribute`***.. etc processors we can make filter only the required flowfiles.
- in this method each flowfile needs to have only one record in it.

  (or)
- By using `RouteOnContent (or) RouteText` processor, refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/140731/how-to-derive-by-generating-conditions-with-routeo.html) link.